# C/C++ log10 function from math.h yields incorrect value

Tags: c++, c, math.h

The following minimal example shows the issue:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   double a = log10(1/200);
   double b = log10(0.005);

   std::cout << "The value of a is " << a << " and b is " << b << std::endl;
}
```

I compile the program using g++:

```
g++ -o math math.cpp
./math
```

The output of the program is:

```
The value of a is -inf and b is -2.30103
```

The same thing occurs with C:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   double a = log10(1/200);
   double b = log10(0.005);

   printf("The value of a is %f and b is %f\n", a, b);
}
```

I compile the program using gcc:

```
gcc -o math math.c -lm
./math
```

The output is again:

```
The value of a is -inf and b is -2.301030
```

The answer in both cases should be -2.30103. Can someone explain to me what is going on?

Comment: `1/200` is zero.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`1/200` is performing integer division, which is 0, so you're doing `log10(0)` which gives you `-inf`.  Try changing that to `log10(1.0/200.0)` (or only one of them should need the decimal) to tell the compiler to do floating point division.

Comment: So obvious now. Thanks.